# Understanding Tensorflow's shape, rank and size

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to see outputs of tf.rank(), tf.shape() and tf.size() but I am getting weird results even for a simple list:

```
   t = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [2, 3, 4]]
```

Below is how the results look like:

```
   In [451]: tf.shape(t)
   Out[451]: <tf.Tensor 'Shape_11:0' shape=(2,) dtype=int32>

   In [452]: tf.size(t)
   Out[452]: <tf.Tensor 'Size_5:0' shape=() dtype=int32>

   In [453]: tf.rank(t)
   Out[453]: <tf.Tensor 'Rank_4:0' shape=() dtype=int32>
```

Can you please explain how to interpret these?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are printing the shapes of `tf.shape(t)`, `tf.size(t)` and `tf.rank(t)` (the tensors, not their results.

Instead, create a session and evaluate those:

```py
t = tf.constant([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [2, 3, 4]])
sess = tf.Session()

print sess.run(tf.shape(t))
print sess.run(tf.size(t))
print sess.run(tf.rank(t))
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much!

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for the same solution.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look only at the first output.

```
In [451]: tf.shape(t)
Out[451]: <tf.Tensor 'Shape_11:0' shape=(2,) dtype=int32>
```

`tf.shape` adds an op in the computational graph and returns a tensor.

This tensor has the name `Shape_11:0` where

1. `Shape` is the name of the op that generated this tensor followed by
2. `_<n>` where `<n>` is the count of the ops of the same kind in the
   graph (calls to `tf.shape`).
   `:<idx>`  is the index of that tensor in the outputs of the operation that produced it.

This tensor has `shape` that's `(2,)`, so it's a 2-D tensor.

This tensor has a `type` that's a `int32`.

The other 2 ops product tensors as well. Following the previous reasoning you can understand their output.

That is the explanation of your output. By the way, if you want to get the result of the operations, you have to evaluate the ops into a session as [Olivier Moindrot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5098368/olivier-moindrot) pointed out in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37901062/2891324).